# PHP - Inject script into the <head>

Tags: php, function, str-replace

Run into a bit of a sticky situation which I can't seem to wrap my finger around. Basically what I am trying to achieve is having the ability to inject different Javascript files on different page.

Some simple, random example:

- Page 1: import **jquery.js**
- Page 2: import **mootools.js**

So what I have done is, I've created a function called `addScript()` like so:

```
function addScript($file) {

    $script = '';
    $script .= '<script src="'. REL_PATH . '/path/to/file/' . $file . '">';
    $script .= '</script>';

    return $script;
}
```

so if I call `addScript('jquery.min');` it, outputs correctly.

What I now want to do is replace the closing `</head>` tag with the output from the above function. If I do the following then it works fine:

```
ob_start();
require_once("models/header.php");
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo str_replace('</head>', addScript('jquery.js') . '</head>', $contents);
```

However I would like this to be a little more dynamic as there may be multiple script that I need to inject on each page like so:

```
addScript('script.js');
addScript('script2.js');
addScript('script3.js');
```

I then thought of creating a `getHead()` function with a foreach loop inside and returning `str_replace` there instead but this did not work.

Can anyone guide my in the direction to dynamically inject as many script as required and output the last bit of the head?

Comment: Forget about hacks like this; just make your header-generating code configurable so that it outputs the desired tags in all cases.

Comment: Your proposed solution - though hacky - should work as is. You're essentially just prepending <script src="..."></script>  to the </head> tag each time.
Alternatively, you could pass in an array of scripts to your addScript function...

Comment: I do not see the problem as well. just pass an array with the scrips and use your replace function in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
class Assets {
    private static $css = array();
    private static $js = array();

    static function add_style($path) {
        self::$css[] = $path;
    }

    static function add_script($path) {
        self::$js[] = $path;
    }

    static function get_styles() {
        $output = '';
        foreach(self::$css as $path) {
            $ouput .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. $path .'" />' . "\n";
        }
        return $ouput;
    }

    static function get_scripts() {
        $output = '';
        foreach(self::$js as $path) {
            $ouput .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. $path .'"></script>' . "\n";
        }
        return $ouput;
    }
}
```

Then anywhere in your project:

```
Assets::add_style('path/to/style.css');
Assets::add_script('path/to/jquery.js');
```

And in header.php:

```
<head>
    <!-- other header stuff -->
    <?php echo Assets::get_styles(); ?>
    <?php echo Assets::get_scripts(); ?>
</head>
```

Is much more convenient, and you can can extend the class to do more fancy stuff.

Disclaimer: there is much debate about using static vars, as they look like globals. I agree, but this is quick-and-dirty and works no matter what kind of framework you use. You can also make the variables oldschool instance vars, but then you'll have to pass the assets object to the header.php as well.

Comment: Thank you, works like ab absolute charm. Only thing I changed was I added `$path` inside the `src=""` attribite rather than inside `<script> </script>`

Comment: ah yeah... sure... stupid me... I guess I need some coffee ;) Changed it in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the following??

```
echo str_replace('</head>',
    addScript('jquery.js').
    addScript('jquer1.js').
    addScript('jquer2.js').
    addScript('jquer3.js').
    '</head>', $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you put the `ob_start();` in `header.php`.  Then your function is:

```
function addScript($file) {    
    $script = '<script src="'. REL_PATH . '/path/to/file/' . $file . '"></script>';
    echo str_replace('</head>', addScript('jquery.js') . '</head>', ob_get_clean());
}
```

Then:

```
addScript('script.js');
```

This method keeps the output buffer going and you can manipulate it later in the script whenever you want. just as you do with the `addScript()`.